# How do I profile disk I/O within a PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, profiling

I am running 5 instances of a PHP script using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html).  Running 5 processes is the optimal number to maximize the processing that my PHP script does.  If I run more than 5 or less than 5, I get worse results.

I'm already profiling the PHP script itself with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/).

I suspect that disk I/O is what's preventing me from running more parallel processes as my CPU and Memory are not maxed out with 5 processes running.  I have 4 virtual cores on an Amazon EC2 instance, and neither Mysqld nor Supervisord are using more than 50% CPU at any given time.

How does one profile disk I/O on a Linux Cent OS machine ( does this sound like the culprit )?

What other bottlenecks should I be looking for?

**--SOLUTION--**

I was unable to find any simple solutions that gave me very in depth information.  I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for though, so I apologize for this question and answer being vague.

Comment: Would using plain old `iotop` be an option? That gives you a live view of what processes are accessing the disk.

Comment: I've installed that and tried it out.  Looks like good data, but I'm unclear what to do with the info?  How do I know what my system limits are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at `iostat -c -n 1` while your script is running and see what is reported in the %util column on the far right. If your hunch is right, then the %util should be close to 100% while your processes are running.

Does this script do any processing that fetches data over the network? That could also be a bottleneck.

Its hard to say more without knowing a little more about what the script does. What is each process doing? How did you determine that 5 is the optimal number of processes?

Comment: It's a crawling/scraping system.  Each script selects the next file from a files table and downloads it if it's not already downloaded.  Then scrapes it and stores various pieces of info like links and meta info. I determined 5 was the optimal # of processes by trying different numbers of processes and tracking how many files per second were being processed.  It maxed at around 2.8 files per second with 5 processes running. I've tried iostat and my %util never goes over 10%. I'll keep digging i guess. Also, I had to use iostat -x 1.

Comment: `yum install sysstat`